# Function to make a smaller list from a larger list python

Tags: python, list, function, python-2.7

I have a list of numbers and I want to make rows and columns out of the list.
I can brute force it and do the following below in Python 2.7.

```
l  = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]    
r1 = [l[0], l[1], l[2]]
r2 = [l[3], l[4], l[5]]
r3 = [l[6], l[7], l[8]]
c1 = [l[0], l[3], l[6]]
```

But I can't seem to create a function in python to make it work. Is my syntax wrong?

```
def make_row(r, li, arg1, arg2, arg3):
    r = [li[arg1], li[arg2], li[arg3]]

make_row(r1, l, 0, 1, 2)
make_row(r2, l, 3, 4, 5)
make_row(r3, l, 6, 7, 8)
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? The `make_row` function does not seem to work correctly.

Comment: The identifier `l` is wildly unreadable. Prefer `s` for sequence.

Comment: Good point, is that last `make_row` call's second argument supposed to be an `l` not a `1`? Seems like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I think i figured out my own question. The code should look like this.

```
def make_row(li, arg1, arg2, arg3):
    r = [li[arg1], li[arg2], li[arg3]]
    return r
row1 = make_row(li, 0, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error is a misunderstanding in [how Python passes arguments](http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/). `r` in the function `make_row` is just a name. When you assign into it, it simply points that name to something new, in the context of your function, leaving the old object, and old name outside the function, unchanged.

If you return the result of `make_row` you can see it generates the correct output, it just does not save it into the variables as you are thinking it would.

---

#### However there are easier (and more Pythonic) ways to do what you are trying to do:

This will return a list of your **rows**:

```
[l[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0, len(l), 3)]
```

And this is the equivalent for **columns**:

```
[l[i::3] for i in xrange(0, 3)]
```

If you want rows/columns of a different length, just substitute that number in place of the 3's in these statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `make_row` works as far as I can tell (I have not tested it), but you need to `return r`.